# Is there a way to monitor sensor data in the background in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am looking at writing a sensor data logger with Codenameone that runs in the background and logs sensor data, and bluetooth LE ids into a database at intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have this API which doesn't work in the background: https://github.com/chen-fishbein/sensors-codenameone/

Newer activity API's are designed exactly for that sort of thing. We don't currently have a builtin abstraction for them but you can probably build such an abstraction based on the work Chen did for that library. So it should be relatively easy to implement in native code but isn't supported out of the box at this time.